# Sending data to peripheral with button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two view controllers set up, a UITableView that handles all the scanning and connecting to devices. Once the device is discovered as well as its Services and Characteristics, I go back to the main screen where I push a button and it sends data to the peripheral I am connected to. Nothing is received however from the peripheral I am reading from. 
When I try to write onto the device from the UITableView it does work however.

Here is the code for the button press

```
- (IBAction)Unlock:(id)sender {


uint8_t val = 12; //data to send
NSData* valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&val length:sizeof(val)];

//check if peripheral is connected
if (!myPeriph) { 
    NSLog(@"Not connected to a peripheral");
}
// check for characteristic 
if (!myChar) {
    NSLog(@"No valid characteristic");
    return;
}
NSLog(@"Writing value for characteristic %@", myChar);
//write data to peripheral
[myPeriph writeValue:valData forCharacteristic:myChar
                 type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];


}
```

And this is the code that works

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{


    // Deal with errors (if any)
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        // [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    // Again, we loop through the array, just in case.
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"Discovered characteristic %@",characteristic);
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {

            // If it is, subscribe to it
            //[peripheral setNotifyValue: forCharacteristic:characteristic];


            //store characteristic as variable
            Connected_Characteristic= characteristic;
            NSLog(@"Connected Char %@",Connected_Characteristic);


            uint8_t val = 12; //data to send
      NSData* valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&val length:sizeof(val)];

         //write data to peripheral
[Connected_Peripheral writeValue:valData forCharacteristic:Connected_Characteristic
                 type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];

        //pass peripheral and characteristic back to main screen        
            [self.delegate didSelectWith:self device:Connected_Peripheral device_characteristics:Connected_Characteristic];

          //pop back to main screen  
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }

    }

}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I thought i might have to be inside that 'didDiscoverCharacteristicsForServices' function, but I've seen another example that call the write method outside it.

Also, myPeriph and myChar are declared here

```
-(void)didSelectWith:(deviceViewController *)controller device:(CBPeripheral *)device device_characteristics:(CBCharacteristic *)device_characteristics

{

    self.myPeriph=device;
    self.myChar=device_characteristics;

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"device %@ characteristic %@ ",myPeriph, myChar);

    }
```

and are passed from the above function and successfully work.

Comment: How do you send `myPeriph` and `myChar` back to the first view controller?  Where is the property that holds a reference to your `CBCentralManager` defined?

Comment: CBCentral manager is defined in the .h file of the UITableView. 
And I'm using a delegate to send the peripheral and characteristics across. 
 
I've done a bit of debugging and I've found out that the 'central manager', 'services' and 'attributes' section of 'myPeriph' are zero in the one that doesn't work and actually have values in the one that does work.

Comment: Your objects are being released.  I suggest that you move all of your Bluetooth operations into their own class and hold a reference to that class instance through an object like your AppDelegate